# Extra whitespaces in vscode css

Tags: visual-studio-code

Default formatter inserts a whitespace at the beginning of each line whenever I save a css file. Example:

[image]

How do I configure Visual Studio code not to insert those spaces?
I tried looking in the Settings with no success

Comment: Can you see "CSS" shown as language mode in the status bar?

Comment: use this extensuion in vs code Intellisense for CSS Class Names

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. are you using any formatting VS Code extensions? Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Reloading with extensions disabled didn't help at all